# Parsing a string with multiple xml files into a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a string s with multiple XML files given below:

```
['https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201611339349202661_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201611309349201761_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201543179349200944_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201631099349200733_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201610909349200511_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201630749349201058_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201601319349200235_public.xml',
 'https://irs-form-990.s3.amazonaws.com/201641069349200909_public.xml',]
```

I have 1000 in that string s and I want to parse all that to a df using pyspark

I am using the below code:

```
df = sql.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="xyze").load(s).coalesce(10)
```

and it is giving me and error

I also used

```
sc.addFile(s)
df4 = sql.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="xyze").load(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("*_public.xml"))
```

It is giving me the same error as Path to XML need to be specified

And I am using jupyter notebook for all these.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the location of xml files are at diffrent place where the scripts are running

you can try below things

1) Add the location of xml files in environment variable

2) if it does not solve problem , create a PPTHONPATH environment variable and specifiy the location here

3)you can just try below code

```
import os
os.chdir(xmlfilepath)
sc.addFile(s)
df4 = sql.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="xyze").load(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("*_public.xml"))
```

This should work